# Run commands before and after a buffer is externally changed

Tags: autocmd

Imagine I have a Vim buffer open and the file is changed externally (example: I switched git branches or the file was just edited normally).

Any time that happens, I want to have 2 commands run. The first command, `Foo` runs right before Vim updates the buffer with the new text and then the second command, `Bar` runs after the buffer is updated. How do I do that?

I tried to use autocmd like this:

```
autocmd! FileChangedShell * Foo
autocmd! FileChangedShellPost * Bar
```

The problem is that it doesn't work. When the buffer updates, only FileChangedShellPost gets called. I tested this using these commands.

```
autocmd! FileChangedShell * echoerr "About to read"
autocmd! FileChangedShellPost * echoerr "read!"
```

When the file is updated, only "read!" is printed.

Right now I'm using `CursorHold,CursorHoldI` to try to simular a "before buffer is read" event but it's hacky. How do I run a command before the Vim buffer gets changed from an external edit?

Comment: I don't think this is possible